# Vue apollo, throws error every time on load

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, graphql, apollo

```
<template>
  <div v-if="loading"><loading></loading></div>
  <div v-else-if="error"><error v-bind="error"/></div>
  <div v-else>
    <div class="title" v-if="!error"> <h1>Recently Added:</h1></div>
    <section class="adverts" >
      
      <adverts @update:isFavorited="updateIsFavorited" v-for="advert in adverts.list" v-bind:key="advert.id" v-bind="advert" />
    </section>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent, reactive, watchEffect } from 'vue';
import { useQuery } from '@vue/apollo-composable'
import { GET_ADVERTS } from "@/graphql/advert";
import Adverts from '../components/Adverts.vue';
import Error from '../components/Error.vue';
import Loading from '../components/Error.vue';

interface Advert {
  id: number;
  location: string;
  price: number;
  title: string;
  createdAt: string;
  available: boolean;
  isFavorited: boolean;
}


export default defineComponent({
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    Adverts,
    Error,
    Loading,
  },
  methods: {
    async loadMoreAdverts() {
        if (this.loading) return; 
        const accessToken = localStorage.getItem("access_token") || "";
        this.loading = true;
        try {
          const { result, error } = await useQuery(GET_ADVERTS,  {
            variables: {
              accessToken,
              offset: this.adverts.list.length,
              limit: 10 
            }
          });

          if (result) {
            this.adverts.list.push(...result.value.getAdverts);
          } else if (error) {
            console.error(error);
          }
        } catch (error) {
          console.error(error);
        } finally {
          this.loading = false;
        }
    }
  },

  setup() {
    const adverts = reactive({ list: [] as Advert[] });

    const accessToken = localStorage.getItem("access_token") || "";


    const updateIsFavorited = (id: number, isFavorited: boolean) => {
      const index = adverts.list.findIndex((advert) => advert.id === id);
      const updatedAdverts = [...adverts.list];
      updatedAdverts[index] = { ...updatedAdverts[index], isFavorited };
      adverts.list = updatedAdverts;
    };

   
    const {result, loading, error} = useQuery(GET_ADVERTS, { accessToken, offset: 1, limit: 4 }, { fetchPolicy: 'network-only' });


    console.log(result, loading, error);

    

    watchEffect(() => {
      if (result.value) {
        adverts.list = result.value.getAdverts;
      }
    });


    

    return {
      adverts,
      loading,
      error,
      updateIsFavorited
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    // this.loadMoreAdverts();
    // const observer = new IntersectionObserver(entries => {
    //     if (entries[0].isIntersecting) {
    //       this.loadMoreAdverts();
    //     }
    // }, { threshold: 1 });

    // observer.observe(this.$refs.loadMoreTrigger);
  },

});
</script>



<style scoped>
  .adverts {
    display:flex;
    justify-content:flex-start;
    align-items:center;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
    gap:30px 30px;
    margin:50px 150px;
  }

  .error {
    height:100%;
  }

  .title {
    display:grid;
  }

  h1 {
    color: rgb(var(--v-theme-text));
    margin: 50px 150px 20px 150px;
    justify-self: flex-start;
  }

</style>
```

i have this code, it fetch adverts, but every time on load i see error message for 1 sec or less,
this pattern is from official documentation https://apollo.vuejs.org/guide-composable/query.html, and i dont think it should work like that, i think it should display loading but not error, because when i check error.value in script it is null

[image]

looks like this